# Input an array into a For Loop but only getting one float out

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, floating-point

I am trying to round down the values in an array `longYearDig` and then convert the values from floats to integers. However, when I input an array with 10 values `longYearDig` I get only one float out `pointyearDig`.

What I am putting in:
`longYearDig = [ 98.32428472  98.32433235  98.32445675  98.32451913  98.32451913
  98.32458141  98.32464367  98.32489267  98.32501715  98.32545376]`

What I want out:

> yearDig = [98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98]
>
> year = [1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime

filename = 'zarya2.txt'
a = np.genfromtxt(filename)

evens = []
odds = []
for i in range(20):   #2913*2
    if np.mod(i,2) == 0:
        evens.append(a[i,:])
    else:
        odds.append(a[i,:])

oddsArray = np.asarray(odds)
evensArray = np.asarray(evens)

'Four Digit Year'
longYearDig = evensArray[:,3] /1000
print 'longYearDig', longYearDig

for i in range(len(longYearDig)):
    pointyearDig = math.floor(longYearDig[i])
print 'pointyearDig', pointyearDig


for i in range(len(pointyearDig)):
    yearDig = int(pointyearDig[i])
print 'yearDig', yearDig


#yearDigit = 98

for i in range(len(yearDig)):
    if yearDig > 17:
        year = yearDig + 1900
    else: 
        year = yearDig + 2000

print('year', year)
```

Outputs:

> longYearDig [ 98.32428472  98.32433235  98.32445675  98.32451913 
>   98.32451913
>     98.32458141  98.32464367  98.32489267  98.32501715  98.32545376]
>
> pointyearDig 98.0
>
> File "/Users/mrmenzel/Desktop/orbits/zaryaISSdataTLE", line 93, in
>   
>       for i in range(len(pointyearDig)):
>
> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: the error is pretty self explanatory.  pointyearDig is a float not an aarry, you cannot call len() on it. I'm a bit confused, why do you want the .0 at the end?

Comment: I don't want the .0 I want just 98 as an integer I will update my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the floor function from numpy

```
longYearDig = evensArray[:,3] /1000
print 'longYearDig', longYearDig
pointyearDig =np.floor(longYearDig)
```

It will apply the floor function to each element and return you the array you want.
Then you can end like this:

```
year = []
for i in range(len(pointyearDig)):
    if pointyearDig[i] > 17:
        year.append(int(pointyearDig[i]) + 1900)
    else: 
        year.append(int(pointyearDig[i]) + 2000)
```

**Another solution:**

You can use the // operator from python, which gives you the floor part of the division. You can compress your code and then have :

```
longYearDig = np.array(evensArray[:,3]) // 1000
year = []
for i in range(len(longYearDig )):
    if longYearDig[i] > 17:
        year.append(longYearDig [i] + 1900)
    else: 
        year.append(longYearDig [i] + 2000)
```